# How can i add custom font and change their style in XML file

Tags: android

I am trying to add new font and change particular text style in android xml file.But i m not getting exact result.

Android code is:

```
 <item ><b>Published by:</b></br>
        <b>Author:</b> abc

                <b>Typesetting and Printing by</b>
                Proficient Publishers
                <b>Content editing:</b> 

                The observations and views expressed in this book are entirely that of the author’s. </item> 
   <item >Whenever the word <b>Bharat</b> or India comes to the mind, one cannot ignore the names
```

Comment: And the result you are expecting is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer for the question without extending the TextView and implementing a long code.

**Code :**

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
```

Place the custom font file in assets folder as usual and try this. It works for me.

Comment: I have a String array containing lots of item in Strings.xml file.each item contains long text and i want some text should be bold or different font and other text should be normal and not bold.

Comment: textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);        // for Bold only

Comment: This code bold all text set in Textview. but I want to change some text bold.

Comment: then do webview to display the content and use CSS to set the style

Answer (score 0):

instead of `<b>my text</b>`  try to use

```
<strong>my text</strong>
```

Comment: not working friend. I want such types. <string-array name ="content">
        
      
      <item ><strong> Published by:</strong></item></string-array>

Comment: I think it is better option to use. <![CDATA[]]>. It works fine.